# Interact with main window while modal window is active

Tags: windows, modal-dialog

I want to be able to interact with main window of applications like Firefox or Word, while modal window is active.

What I mean by interact is to:

- Copy text
- Move window
- Close window (by pressing x button)

Are these possible under Windows environment?

Answer (score 0):

No, the modal windows hide the parent's messaging loop so no events get processed by them.

Comment: Your conclusion is technically wrong, the overriden message loop still dispatches messages to parent windows, so events do get processed by them. This is the reason for example windows still redraw if needed, even if they have modal dialogs visible. Whether the main window will process semantic things such as text input, etc... is of course based on how the application is built.

Comment: `WM_PAINT` isn't sent by your application. We'll just agree to disagree on that, but I would really look up how the Windows message loop works, never know when it may come in handy!

Comment: Whoever sends it, the basic premise "so no events get processed by them [parent windows of a modal dialog]" is wrong. They do get processed because dialog's internal loop does dispatch messages sent to parent windows. I pointed it out so future people don't get confused by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically, you can.  SendMessage will invoke the target window's message handler when the target isn't expecting it, so you'd better be very careful what you do.

If you want to do it as a user, operating the mouse and keyboard, then your question belongs on a different web site even though Blindy answered that question for you.